# ANR in Alarm Manager Android

Tags: android, android-studio, repeatingalarm

[libc.so] __futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)
Broadcast of Intent { cmp

Comment: Kindly add more details on what task you are performing and when you are receiving the error so that better solution can be provided.

Comment: I'm only getting the in the play store after report it manually nothing other than this